# Run multiple tests from a previous saved state

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

I see Cypress lets us get back to the application state during a test to debug [using time-travel](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-runner#Hovering-on-Commands). Is it possible to use this state snapshot as a starting point for other tests?

Imagine a UI where options in a stepper depend on previous selections in earlier steps, and many of these rely on requests to an API. To run different tests in the last step I would need to complete the earlier steps in exactly the same way each time. This can be added to the `before` block to make the code simpler but we still have the delay and overheads of API requests each time to get to this exact same state. Given that Cypress already stores the state at various points, can I seed future tests with the state from previous ones?

Comment: Cypress best practices recommend to test each spec in isolation https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Organizing-Tests-Logging-In-Controlling-State